# Get values from URL using GET from encode UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

let me start by saying that I have no idea how to formulate this question, I have spend the last two days looking for some ways to to the following.
I send some information encoded using base64 as follow....
Values are:
**Lóms Gruñes**
 
this values came from an input box
beacuse of that I do this
**$name = htmlentities(( $_POST ['name'] ) , ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');**
**$midn = htmlentities(( $_POST ['midn'] ) , ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');**
the output for this should be

```
L&oacute;ms Gru&ntilde;es
```

And that is what gets encode, until that everything is fine, and I can do whatever I need with that, in this case I'm going to encode it using base64

```
 $datas ='&name='. $name .'&midn='. $midn;
    $bd = base64_encode($datas);
   // Now lets send that info to another file..
   header( 'Location: other.php?d=$db' ) ;
```

So the url will be something like
**domain.com/other.php?d=TCZvYWN1dGU7bXMgR3J1Jm50aWxkZTtlcw==**

So now lets decode it so that it can be saved...

```
$ds = base64_decode($_GET['d']);
parse_str($ds, $params);
$name = htmlentities($params['name'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
$midn = htmlentities($params['midn'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

It looks pretty straight forward isn't it... but here is the problem because when I try to use the values nothing happen... lets say I just want to echo it...

```
echo $name . '<br>';
echo $midn;
```

What I get is
**L**
**Gru**
so where is the ó and the ñ?
ok, let say I don't encode anything so the URL will look like this...

```
    domain.com/other.php?name=L&oacute;ms&midn=Gru&ntilde;es
// and the I use echo like this:
echo $_GET['name'] . '<br>';
echo $_GET['midn'];
// the output is
L
Gru
```

Even if I put : header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); after the `<?php` ... nothing happen... so, the question... how can I get the `&oacute;` as a value or better yet, how can I send the í,ó,ñ,á...etc as is in the url domain.com/file.php?data=íÄÑó and retrive it as is and save it as is and display it as is... 
I;m not sure if this has some relevant information, the data is going to be saved in a DB, the DB is InnoDB, utf8_general_ci

Thank you for taking the time...

Comment: `&` is used to separate name/value pairs in the [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded* encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), so the `&` in `&oacute;` and `&ntilde;` mark the end of the previous name/value pair. You need to encode the values properly using `urlencode` (`parse_str` already decodes them).

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding), [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always escape/encode for the technology you're using.

To get the UTF-8 encoded values from the form submission:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$midn = $_POST['midn'];
```

To output those into HTML:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
```

To embed them in a URL:

```
$url = sprintf('foo.php?name=%s&midn=%s', rawurlencode($name), rawurlencode($midn));

// or

$url = 'foo.php?' . http_build_query(array('name' => $name, 'midn' => $midn));
```

In `foo.php`, to get the values back:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$midn = $_GET['midn'];
```

And again, to output those into HTML:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
```

And that's basically all you need to do. Always escape values using the right function for the medium, don't escape more or earlier than you need to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to decode htmlentities try [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)().
For encoding the url try [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)().

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
    $query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
    echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you . Instead of using htmlentites I used  rawurlencode and rawurldecode function .

Below is same code

1. First get the values from the

> $name  = rawurlencode('Lóms Gruñes'); use can use //( $_POST ['name']
>
> ```
> $mid = rawurlencode('Gru&ntilde;es'); and here ($_POST ['midn'] )
> ```

then

```
 echo $datas ='name='. $name .'midn='. $midn;
    $en = base64_encode($datas);
```

Append this on next url . Then get the value and decode it using base64_decode function

```
$dd = base64_decode($en);
parse_str($dd);
echo $name;
echo $midn;
```